# Exclude some characters from asciifolding conversion

Tags: elasticsearch

I have setup a analyzer with asciifolding filter.

This filter replaces the letter ç=>c and ñ=>n. I need to keep the original ç and ñ in the token.

Is there a way to setup a exception in the asciifolding filter? If not, I can use a char_filter to do what asciifolding filter do for accents and not for ç and ñ or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any configuration for exceptions in asciifolding, so I have setup a char_filter with the mappings I need and apply in my analyzer (without asciifolding):

char_filter: {
     my_map: {
        type: "mapping",
        mappings: [ "á" => "a", "à" => "a" .... ]
      }
   }