# Alternatives to `asciifolding` filter for removing Greek ascents from unicode text

Tags: diacritics, non-ascii-characters, opensearch, accent-insensitive, unaccent

I see that the `asciifolding` filter of OpenSearch only handles Latin accents and does not handle Greek at all (note: some accents are not rendered well in this site due to the font used):

```
POST /_analyze
{
  "text": [ "Latin: ấ ê ŏ õ ô ì / Greek: ἆ ᾧ ῦ ἄ ἒ " ],
  "filter": [
    "asciifolding"
    ]
}
```

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Latin: a e o o o i / Greek: ἆ ᾧ ῦ ἄ ἒ ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 38,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any other filter that can handle Unicode characters, that I can use to process Greek and remove accents/diacritics, or I will have to roll out my own?

I have found those two alternative ways to achieve my goal, but I was hoping that something built-in would exist for something so basic:

1. [Exclude some characters from asciifolding conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076058/exclude-some-characters-from-asciifolding-conversion)
2. [Elasticsearch modify asciifolding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918255/elasticsearch-modify-asciifolding)

Any hints or ideas are welcome.

Comment: An asciifolding filter filters, well, only (to) ascii, so that is expected. There is also a GreekLowerCaseFilter (deprecated I think?) and the ICUFoldingFilter which folds ascii, Greek, Hebrew, Math and a number of other things.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Marijn! The `icu_folding` filter sounds like what I want! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-folding.html  Feel free to add this as an answer.

Comment: @Marijn However, this does not seem available to OpenSearch out-of-the-box. Perhaps I will need to include some JAR file or something...